# How to get the Max value of each column not used by groupBy in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For a spark dataframe `df` I have
`(col1, col2, col3)` for groupBy operation, i.e., `df.groupBy(col1, col2, col3)`, for other columns in `df` `col4`, `col5`, etc. So how should I get the table with the max value of `col4`, `col5` within each group from `(col1, col2, col3)`? I am expecting some operation like:

`df.groupBy(col1, col2, col3).max(...)`

The result should look like

```
+---------+--------+---------+----+---+
|col1     |col2    |col3_max |col4_max|
+---------+--------+---------+----+---+
|1021     |a       |  .      | .      |
|1000     |b       |  .      | .      |
|1011     |c       |  .      | .      |
+---------+--------+---+----+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work.  I just tried it by opening a `spark-shell`.

```
scala> val df = Seq((1,2,3,4,5,6), (1,2,3,9,3,2), (2,3,3,1,1,1).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: int, col2: int ... 4 more fields]
scala> df.groupBy("col1", "col2", "col3").max("col4", "col5", "col6").show()
+----+----+----+---------+---------+---------+
|col1|col2|col3|max(col4)|max(col5)|max(col6)|
+----+----+----+---------+---------+---------+
|   2|   3|   3|        1|        1|        1|
|   1|   2|   3|        9|        5|        6|
+----+----+----+---------+---------+---------+
```

If you wanted all columns without naming them, you could do the below, but you'll need to filter out the max of col1, col2, & col3:

```
scala> df.groupBy("col1", "col2", "col3").max().show()
+----+----+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|col1|col2|col3|max(col1)|max(col2)|max(col3)|max(col4)|max(col5)|max(col6)|
+----+----+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   2|   3|   3|        2|        3|        3|        1|        1|        1|
|   1|   2|   3|        1|        2|        3|        9|        5|        6|
+----+----+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: But if I have many columns rather than col 4-6, how should I do the same thing? Thanks.